# Accessing processing algorithm results from Whitebox Tools in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, whitebox-tools

When I run a GDAL processing algorithm from the Python Console in QGIS that loads a result raster:

```
resultClip = processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", { 
                                          'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 
                                          'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 
                                          'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 
                                          'EXTRA' : '', 
                                          'INPUT' : 'E:/geodata/nsw100k.vrt', 
                                          'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 
                                          'MASK' : 'C:/Users/brennant/Downloads/data.geojson', 
                                          'MULTITHREADING' : False, 
                                          'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 
                                          'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 
                                          'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 
                                          'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 
                                          'TARGET_CRS' : None, 
                                          'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 
                                          'Y_RESOLUTION' : None })
```

I can access the temporary raster output file via
`resultClip['OUTPUT']`

However, when I do the same thing with one of the Whitebox Tools algorithms (eg BreachDepressions):

```
resultBreach = processing.runAndLoadResults("wbt:BreachDepressions", { 'dem' : resultClip['OUTPUT'], 'max_depth' : '20.0', 'flat_increment' : 0.00001, 'fill_pits' : 1, 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' })
```

`resultBreach['output']` returns a `QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition` variable:

```
<QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {}}>}
```

The temporary layer is created and loaded in the layers window, but from a PyQGIS processing point of view, I can't see how to access it for use in future steps.

And if I look at both algorithms using processing.algorithmHelp
eg

```
processing.algorithmHelp("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer")
```

the output type for both is the same (QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer)

Suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be identical for the one raised in:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/41719

and this is still an open issue.

The best workaround I have found is to use `QgsProcessingUtils.generateTempFilename()` to generate a temporary file. The main catch is that you need to pass a filename (and type), but QGIS handles the temporary folder requirements.

eg

```
resultBreach = processing.runAndLoadResults("wbt:BreachDepressions", { 
    'dem' : resultClip['OUTPUT'], 
    'max_depth' : '20.0', 
    'flat_increment' : 0.00001, 
    'fill_pits' : 1, 
    'output' : QgsProcessingUtils.generateTempFilename('output.tif') 
})
```

(From [QGIS Processing algorithm output](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384759/qgis-processing-algorithm-output/385167#385167))

Answer (score 1):

Temporary files are stored in special folders in your PC. When you turn it off, all temporary files are automatically deleted. For some reason, developers of **Whitebox** implemented an automatic deletion of files when they are created as 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' in a processing tool algorithm with 'run' and 'runAndLoadResults' methods. However, this is not a problem. In my Linux operating system, temporary files are stored in **/tmp** folder. If you use a **Windows** system you can read [this article](https://www.askvg.com/where-does-windows-store-temporary-files-and-how-to-change-temp-folder-location/) for information of where is TEMP Folder Location in that system.

For testing "wbt:BreachDepressions" tool, my output file (OutputFile.tif) was put in **/tmp** folder as parameter definitions. I used 'run' method for not retrieving it from that folder with that tool. So, in same code, for accessing created file, I can define a new layer as:

```
new_layer = QgsRasterLayer('/tmp/OutputFile.tif', 
            'OutputFile')
```

Only for visualization purpose, for proving this layer was created, I loaded it with 'addMapLayer' method of **QgsProject**. On the other hand, I also can probe it with:

```
>>>resultBreach['output']
'/tmp/OutputFile.tif'
```

in Python Console. This is a better option for use in future steps.

Complete code looks as follows:

```
import processing

layer = iface.activeLayer()

resultBreach = processing.run("wbt:BreachDepressions", 
                                          { 'dem' : layer, 
                                            'max_depth' : '20.0', 
                                            'flat_increment' : 0.00001, 
                                            'fill_pits' : 1, 
                                            'output' : '/tmp/OutputFile.tif' })

new_layer = QgsRasterLayer('/tmp/test.tif', 
            'OutputFile')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)

print("done");
```

After running above code in Python Console of QGIS, it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however the key point is that I am trying to avoid specifying a fixed file path in the processing.run step, because it will be system-dependent. For example, I'm on Windows, so I can't use your code without editing. If I can use PyQGIS to access the path of the file, then the code will be system-independent. I can do this for GDAL and SAGA tools, but not (currently) for WhiteBox tools.

Comment: That is not completely true. Based in this article https://www.askvg.com/where-does-windows-store-temporary-files-and-how-to-change-temp-folder-location/ you will have TEMP and TMP variables in your Windows system (you only need to explore them). So, you can also do `resultBreach['output']` and result will be equivalent to other processing tools. Code would be completely portable.

Comment: As per the original question, resultBreach['output'] for Whitebox tools is not equivalent to other tools when TEMPORARY_OUTPUT is set. It's a QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition instead of a file path. I'm trying to access the file path.